# what is the reason for strcpy error

Tags: c, linux, string, struct, strcpy

When I try to execute this program I am getting segmentation fault. What could be the reason?

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<malloc.h>
    #include<string.h>

    #define UWT unsigned int 
    #define DIR_LEN 1024
    typedef struct fileParsedData{
            UWT weight;
            char *dir;
    }FILEPARSEDATA;

    int parseData(char *fileData,FILEPARSEDATA *fPD){

            char tmpStr[DIR_LEN] = {0};

            strcpy(tmpStr,strchr(fileData,' ') + 1);
            *(strchr(tmpStr,'\n')) = '\0';
            fPD->weight = atoi(fileData);

            if((fPD->dir = (char *)malloc(strlen(tmpStr) + 1)) != NULL ){
                    memset(&fPD->dir,0,strlen(tmpStr)+1);
                    strcpy(fPD->dir,tmpStr);
                    return 0;
            }
            return -1;
    }

    int main(){
            char fileData[10] = " hai\n";
            FILEPARSEDATA fPD;
            memset(&fPD,0,sizeof(FILEPARSEDATA));
            parseData(fileData,&fPD);
            return 0;
    }
```

Comment: note too - your `strcpy(tmpStr,strchr(fileData,' ') + 1);` is going to explode if there is no SPACE in your string`

Comment: ...and the whole thing is risky if the incoming data overflows the "magic number" `DIR_LEN`=1024; consider `strncpy` ...

Comment: I have realized the mistake as soon as I posted this :)

Comment: @KevinDTimm String alway starts with space.

Comment: @Thangaraj - you may believe that now, but it will not always be true (btw, if that were the case, there is no point in calling `strchr`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
memset(&fPD->dir,0,strlen(tmpStr)+1);
```

The above line should read:

```
memset(fPD->dir,0,strlen(tmpStr)+1);
```

Otherwise, you're not only zeroing out the `fPD->dir` **pointer**, you're also corrupting memory immediately after it. Once you've zeroed out the pointer, the subsequent `strcpy()` into the pointed-to memory segfaults.

In fact, that entire `memset()` line appears redundant since it's followed immediately by the `strcpy()`.

Comment: To zero the allocated data, use `calloc()`.  There can be occasions when it is reasonable zero memory before using a subset of it - but this isn't one of them, so `malloc()` is fine and the `memset()` is superfluous.